# How to connect Java desktop application to an online mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql

As titled, I want to make my desktop java application to connect to an online mysql db ?! How can I reach it such connection to be able to add and retrieve data?!

Comment: What do you mean, "online db?"  Normally, you would us a JDBC connection over a network.

Comment: free databases; like this one : http://www.freesqldatabase.com/freemysqldatabase/

Comment: i signed up with the same site as you - can you show me how to connect to their database??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the connector from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Add it to your classpath and in the code:

```
// This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  // Setup the connection with the DB
  connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://remoteUri/database-name?"
          + "user=user&password=userpw");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You could directly connect and let the queries run over the network (via JDBC)[example: vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)
2. You build an RESTful Service, there are lots of tutorials as Example;

[RESTful Web Services API using Java and MySQL](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

By all means, a JDBC connection is the way to go. But, you must make sure that the MySQL users have access to the database from another IP Address (i.e. your desktop application).

MySQL users are set up so that they can access the database on the local machine. Therefore, you have to allow access to the MySQL database from any host. Please see the following [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mysql-give-root-user-logon-permission-from-any-host/) which shows how to do that.