# Java SE Connect desktop app to online database

Tags: java, mysql

please, I have a java desktop app, I want a way to connect my desktop app to an online database. I want to know the technologies that are available to do this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eben. Please read [ask] on how you can avoid downvotes. Generally, this type of question is off topic. You should show some research effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Java desktop application to an online mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362693/how-to-connect-java-desktop-application-to-an-online-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use JDBC.

You have to create a connection with the properties of your database for example :

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://server_ip/database_name", "username", "password");
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have got the connection string.  But do you have any idea of a site that allows remote connection to an online mysql for testing?

Comment: there are a lot @Eben for example https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/ or https://www.db4free.net/ just type in google free mysql hosting and you will find many good luck

Comment: Thank you.   I am very grateful

Comment: Thank you @ YCF_L, that solved my problem. I have got the connection to the hosting server.